# Do the two clauses mean the same?

Tags: sentence-construction

> The company has provided a lot of information, **which enables** a
>   comprehensive investigation of the corruption case.
>
> The company has
>   provided a lot of information, **enabling** a comprehensive investigation
>   of the corruption case.

Do the two sentences mean the same? does the second one omit 'which is'? if so, the present tense has become present continuous. Wouldn't that change the meaning of the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the two sentences have identical meanings.
The second example isn't present continuous tense. It's a present participle at the head of a participle phrase which modifies the preceding clause.

Answer (score 0):

The two sentences have the same meaning.

The second one does not omit 'which is'. The original clause with 'which is'

> which enables a comprehensive investigation of the corruption case

reduced to

> enabling a comprehensive investigation of the corruption case

and functions as an sentence adverbial phrase to modify the first half, "The company has provided a lot of information".

more info about sentence adverb, see [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/241002/109190).